# two queries in same method

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to execute two queries in the same method but it gives me this exception. I can get red of this exception by declaring new command but is there any way to use the same command?

```
string id="hi";
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
        command1.Connection = connection;
        string query1 = "select * from products where category='" + comboBox1.Text + "' and subcategory = '" + comboBox2.Text + "' and sizes='" + comboBox3.Text + "'";
        command1.CommandText = query1;
        OleDbDataReader reader = command1.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            id = reader[0].ToString();
        }
        textBox1.Text = id;

        string query = "insert into category_in  (category_id,amount,amount_in) values ('"+ id+"' ,500,300)";
        command1.CommandText = query;
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("saved");
        connection.Close();
```

Comment: It gives you *what* exception?  The first step in correcting an error is *reading the error*.  Also note that your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: This only writes the *last* id value btw which is effectively a random one from the rows in the select - if you expect a *single* id use ExecuteScalar()

Comment: …And prone to *resourse leak*: you don't free resources on error. Use `using` when working with `IDisposable`, e.g. `using (OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand()) {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your `OleDbDataReader` object when you are finished with it:

```
// previous code omitted for brevity
//

while (reader.Read())
{
    id = reader[0].ToString();
}

// need to close reader
//
reader.Close();

// run your other query (omitted for brevity)
```

And as the comment on your question states, the way you construct your query is extremely vulnerable to a SQL inject attack.  [Parameterize your query](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) the proper way.

As per Dmitry's comment, I completely agree.  Wrap your `OleDbDataReader` object in a `using` block to call `OleDbDataReader.Dispose()` upon completion of the block:

```
using (OleDbDataReader reader = command1.ExecuteReader()) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `using (var reader = command1.ExecuteReader()) {...}` is far better than `reader.Close();`: no *resource leak* on errors and more *readable* code

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Totally agree, I have added that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the reader after first execution,so code will be like this

```
string id="hi";
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
        command1.Connection = connection;
        string query1 = "select * from products where category='" + comboBox1.Text + "' and subcategory = '" + comboBox2.Text + "' and sizes='" + comboBox3.Text + "'";
        command1.CommandText = query1;
        OleDbDataReader reader = command1.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            id = reader[0].ToString();
        }
        textBox1.Text = id;
        ////////code for closing the reader/////////////
        reader.Close();
        ///////////////
        string query = "insert into category_in  (category_id,amount,amount_in) values ('"+ id+"' ,500,300)";
        command1.CommandText = query;
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("saved");
        connection.Close();
```